# Covering finite groups by unions of proper subgroups

Tags: group-theory

A noncyclic finite group $G$ may be expressed as a union of some of its proper subgroups. (Say the subgroups "cover" $G$ in this case.) A relatively simple exercise in some introductory algebra texts, e.g. Jacobson [Basic Algebra I, 2ed p 36 ex 14 ], is to show that no group is the union of two proper subgroups. So I thought what if one is allowed more proper subgroups? One cannot express a cyclic group as a union of proper subgroups, since one of the subgroups would containing the generator and hence fail to be proper. On the other hand, if $G$ is noncyclic it has such an expression, since one can form all the cyclic groups generated by the elements of $G$, and then their union is $G$ and each is proper since $G$ is not cyclic.

My question is about the minimal number of proper subgroups needed to cover a given noncyclic group $G.$ If this minimal number is denoted $m(G)$ then I found e.g. $m(S_3)=4$ and also $m(K)=3$ for the symmetric group $S_3$ and the Klein four-group $K.$
I would be interested if anything is known about $m(S_n)$ generally, or in what $m(G)$ turns out to be for other families of groups. (Even some more examples of $m(S_n)$ for small $n$ would be nice.) Another interesting case might be for the multiplicative groups of invertible elements mod $n$ (in cases where no primitive root exists.)

Comment: While I haven't encountered this number studied anywhere, there are some elementary things to be said, e.g. a non-cyclic finite group is certainly equal to the union of all its maximal subgroups, so $m(G)$ is bounded above by the number of maximal subgroups, a much more well-known invariant.

Comment: @AlastairLitterick It looks like one could replace the term "proper subgroup" by the seemingly more restrictive term "maximal proper subgroup" in defining $m(G),$ since in any union $H_1 \cup \cdots H_n=G$ of proper subgroups each non-maximal $H_k$ could be replaced by a maximal proper subgroup $E_k$ which contained $H_k.$ In other words I think the two definitions would wind up equivalent. But that still leaves open how to get $m(G)$ for specific $G.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-studied invariant, going back to G. Scorza who, in 1926, showed that the groups $G$ with $m(G) = 3$ are those with $C_2^2$ as a homomorphic image.  But much has been done since then.  [Here](http://www.math.unipd.it/~mgaronzi/defense-dottorato.pdf) are some nice slides from a talk by Martino Garonzi.  It, and the references at the end, should get you started.

Comment: Nice reference of Garonzi!

Answer (score 4):

As you noted, a group cannot be the union of two of its proper subgroups. It might be interesting to know, that research has been done on how this might generalize.

**Theorem** (Bruckheimer, Bryan and Muir) A group is the union of three proper subgroups if and only if it has a quotient isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$.

The proof appeared in the American Math. Monthly $77$, no. $1 (1970)$. The theorem seems to be proved earlier by the Italian mathematician Gaetano Scorza, *I gruppi che possono pensarsi come somma di tre loro sottogruppi*, Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. $5 (1926), 216-218$.

For 4, 5 or 6 subgroups a similar theorem is true and the Klein 4-group is for each of the cases replaced by some finite set of groups. For 7 subgroups however, it is not true: no group can be written as a union of 7 of its proper subgroups. This was proved by Tomkinson in 1997.

There is a nice overview paper by Mira Bhargava, *Groups as unions of subgroups*, The American Mathematical Monthly, $116$, no. $5, (2009)$.